# Trouble with page header code being added to a cfc call from a bind

Tags: ajax, coldfusion, cfc, application.cfc

I have some includes in my onRequestStart() Method which I have by-passed for cfc requests using: `<cfif listLast(arguments.thePage, ".") neq "cfc">` (which I got from Ray Camden on a forum here http://forums.forta.com/messages.cfm?threadid=10C19539-E898-C4C8-5F32EBA5B054C3D6 thanks Ray!)

However, I still have code being added to my JSON response:

```
`[[46,"Childcare Volunteer Costa Rica"],[59,"Conservation Volunteer Costa Rica"],[111,"Ecotourism Volunteer Costa Rica"],[25,"Emergency Response Volunteer  Costa Rica"],[52,"Grant Writing & Fundraising Volunteer- Costa Rica"],[13,"Medical Volunteer Costa Rica"],[19,"Nursing Volunteer Costa Rica"],[39,"Patient Care Volunteer- Costa Rica"],[32,"Public Health Volunteer- Costa Rica"],[103,"Reading Week Wildlife Project"],[73,"Special Needs Volunteer Costa Rica"],[117,"Volunteer Teaching All Ages Costa Rica"],[89,"Volunteer Teaching Classroom- Costa Rica"],[96,"Volunteer Vocational Training- Costa Rica"],[66,"Webdesign & Computer Volunteer- Costa Rica"],[114,"Wildlife Volunteer Costa Rica"],[80,"Youth Outreach Volunteer Costa Rica"]]**<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>`
```

Any ideas where else this might be being inserted or what I may be missing? (I am not using onRequest or onRequestEnd right now, and i don't think there is anything else in the application.cfc that would be adding this)

Thanks in advance for any help....

Answer (score 2):

Well the first thing to do is to locate where that code exists in your codebase (it cannot simply be appearing out of the ether), and then work backwards from that to work out how it's getting appended to your response.

One question: there's two asterisks between the end of the JSON and the beginning of the empty XHTML template.  Is that actually there in the response, or did you add it in as a highlight?

One thing to do would be to hit the URL you're calling via your AJAX call directly in a browser, with debugging switched on, and check the files that are composing the response.  That should give you a good heads-up of what's going on.

But for a normal install, the only place stuff gets automatically run from is your Application.cfc.  Anything else will only get called in specifically via your code.

Are you certain you are looking at the correct Application.cfc, and there is not another one between the file you're requesting, and the one you're looking at?  Because it's the "nearest ancestor" Application.cfc that is used, not necessarily the one in your doc root.

Which version of CF are you using (it's always handy if you specify this in your question).

Comment: @ Adam...Hey thanks very much for your response...your comment got me thinking that I could just drop an empty template for an Application.cfc in the CFC folder ..... worked like a charm.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is not the best place to do your includes, this stuff is generally done using an event model.
How a workaroung would perhaps be to look at the requested file and only do your include for .cfm files and nothing else.

Comment: Yeah I agree.  I built a customized CMS & CRM with sort of a home-hacked framework.  I still have a lot of clean-up to do, but I am running several live sites off the system and the clean-up is going to take a while.....FYI: A blank Application.cfc in the CFC folder did the trick.